# Need to achieve synchronization using memory built-in functions in compute shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to know how memory built-in functions works in compute shaders. Thus was experimenting below code.

Using NIVIDA OPENGL 4.3, GL 430.

compute shader:

```
layout (local_size_x = 128, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(std140, binding=1) buffer Res{
 coherent int result;
};
void main()
{
 int a=0;
 result=1;
 a = atomicAdd(result, 1);
 //barrier();
 //memoryBarrier()
}
```

In program, launching work group as

```
 glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObj, nResult);
 glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, bufferObj);
 glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
 glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, bufferObj);

 glDispatchCompute(17,1,1);
 glMemoryBarrier(GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT);

 buffer = (GLint*)glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 4, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
 printf("value =%d", *buffer);
 glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
```

But for every execution I am getting random values of 'result' buffer variable.Tried to use memory functions , but still not working.
Getting correct results till num_groups_x =16. Also till num_groups_x=16 it does not need any memory functions in shader as well.

Answer (score 1):

The barrier functions will prevent invocations of your shader from executing beyond a certain point until all have reached it. It effectively influences scheduling to prevent data hazards. Otherwise, they will all execute in any haphazard order the GPU/driver chooses. Compute shaders actually add a new kind of barrier for synchronizing only invocations of the shader within the same workgroup, called memoryBarrierShared.

That is kind of a silly place to put a memory barrier, by the way. Literally ***nothing*** happens after the barrier, so I do not see why you would want to add a synchronization point there. Usually you only introduce memory barriers at the shader-level when you need to make sure all other invocations of the shader have completed something like a `load` before you go ahead and overwrite the same resource with a `store`. You introduce an artificial stall in the name of synchronization. I am referring to the commented out barriers in your shader.

---

Now, there is another issue in this code that really has nothing to do with synchronization at all and may explain your problem. You are returning a pointer to mapped memory from your buffer object (`buffer = (GLint*)glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 4, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);`) and before you do anything with that pointer, you unmap the memory. Thus, `buffer` points to invalid memory and results will be undefined - you might crash your program or simply read garbage memory.

`buffer` is only valid while it is mapped.

What is more, at the beginning of your code excerpt, `buffer` is the name of a buffer object. At the end of the excerpt it is being used to store a pointer to memory. `glGenBuffers (...)` also only takes 2 parameters in the C language bindings. Either your compiler is asleep at the wheel, you pasted this code wrong, or this is some language other than C.

Comment: 'buffer' one is typing mistake, I didn't paste the compiled code here, because of some reasons. Edited the code above. Actually I wanted to know or produce any scenario where I can use memory functions. Thus was trying different codes, And encountered above issue. I searched a lot but was not able get any working code which would explain this.

Comment: So... you are actually just looking for a scenario where you would want to use a barrier inside of a shader? The easiest example would involve an image load/store. I am sure there are lots (relatively speaking, since this is a new feature) of tutorials out there that include memory barriers in their discussion of image load/store.